# How can I PREVENT microsoft excel from being opened by a third party program

Tags: excel, windows, path, environment-variables

We have an internal WPF program and when you click an export button it downloads an .xlsx sheet and opens it in excel.

I want the download, but I'm downloading many sheets so I do not want excel to open at all. What can I do to prevent this app from knowing I have excel? Do I have to temporarily un-associate .xlsx with excel.exe?

Are there any more elegant solutions?

Comment: I seems that your WPF program opens each document using Excel. The obvious and direct way would be to modify the program. However, Windows does know to open an XLSX file with Excel because of the association you mention. If you deprive Windows of this hint it would depend upon the WPF program how to deal with the situation. The options are a) give an error message, b) ignore and proceed without opening and c) crash. I keep by fingers crossed for b).

Comment: totally crashes when I delete the file association. I am able to change it to open in notepad which is much faster and will do as a dirty work around.